# Require Input Claims From JWT From RelyingParty in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm [sending hidden claims to B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_invitation.xml) via a JWT following the [WingTig Games demo code](https://wingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net/Invitation/Create). How do I require claim(s) to be sent by the relying party? And if they are not sent, prevent the sign-up process?  And provide my own error message to the user?  These fields will be hidden from the user.

I tried adding required in my leaf policy in the `RelyingParty` node but it let me through.  I tried adding required to my `TechnicalProfile` node but it let me through.

```xml
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_my_claim" Required="true"/>
</InputClaims>
```

Comment: I'd expect this to be enforced by the TechnicalProfile. What I'd guess is happening is that you are getting the claims, it's just empty. In that case, you'd need extra validation for it which you could achieve via the [<Restriction><Pattern>](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L35) element of the claim itself.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, thus adding it as a comment, hopefully, someone else can provide a more definitive answer here.

Comment: Thanks @Saca.  I should have mentioned the fields are hidden from the user (I've updated the question).  I tried the <Restriction><Pattern> and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can add pre-condition to steps 1&2 then add additional step with your customer error page.

In the XML snippet below, I have added pre-conditions that run the steps 1&2 only if your claim exists, otherwise skip to the next step.
On sept 3, the pre-condition is run only if the claims does not exist, then display custom page. It’s just an example, in your case you can add your own error page.

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>{your claim name}</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>{your claim name}</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>

  <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
    <Value>registrationSource</Value>
    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
  </Precondition>

  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" />
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<!-- Error message-->
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ReviewScreen" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.selfasserted">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>registrationSource</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
</OrchestrationStep>


<!-- Rest of the UserJourney -->
</OrchestrationSteps>
</UserJourney>
```

Locate the `<ContentDefinitions>` element, and add following XML

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id=" api.inputtoken.error ">
   <LoadUri>~/tenant/default/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
   <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
   <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri>
   <Metadata>
       <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
   </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

Change the LoadUri value to point to your HTML error page